# improper use of Vue transition?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, transition

I have an element that acts as an image carousel by swapping out the `src` of an `img` every 3 seconds:

**JS**

```
data() {

 return {

  carousel: {

    images: [
      "/images/beauty.png",
      "/images/dance.png",
      "/images/funny.png",
      "/images/sweet.png"
    ],
    currentNumber: 0,
    timer: null 
  }   
 } 
}

methods: {
  startRotation: function() {
    this.carousel.timer = setInterval(this.next, 3000);
  },
  next: function() {
    this.carousel.currentNumber += 1
  }
}
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="grid__slide">
  <div class="grid__slide-inner" v-for="number in [carousel.currentNumber]">
    <transition
      name="ease-out-transition"
      leave-active-class="fadeOut"
      mode="out-in"
      >
      <img :src="carousel.images[Math.abs(carousel.currentNumber) % carousel.images.length]">
    </transition>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.fadeOut {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
  animation-name: fadeOut;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}
```

Everything functions except the transition wrapping the `img` element. Any suggestions as to why its ineffective?

Comment: Add a `:key` to the image, so transition sees that the element changes, as opposed to its content

Comment: Transitions apply to elements, not to attribute changes. You can assign  a new key to the image element with `:key="..."`. At least that *should* work :) Edit: Ferrybig beat me to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained inside chapter ["Transitioning Between Elements" in the documentation about `<transition>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Elements), you need to add a [`:key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) element when trying to transition between multiple elements of the same type.

```
<img
    :src="carousel.images[Math.abs(carousel.currentNumber) % carousel.images.length]"
    :key="Math.abs(carousel.currentNumber) % carousel.images.length"
>
```

The reason this is needed because without the `key` attribute, Vue tries to optimize the speed of your application and instead of swapping the image element, it just changes the `src` attribute to point to your new image.

Comment: KEYS, KEYS ARE ALWAYS THE ANSWER